# JavaFX is not displaying JPG files

Tags: java, javafx, jpeg

For some reason, my application is not showing JPG files within a JavaFX window. It does not matter if I'm trying to display the image inside an ImageViewer node or setting it as a background with the CSS `-fx-background-image: url(...);` property.

- I have tried with different jpg files. It did not work.
- I have tried with different image extensions (png, gif). It **did** work.

I'm using OpenJDK 16+36 (I tested with Hotspot and OpenJ9 JVM), JavaFX 16, my operating system is Linux 5.11.16 and my window manager is GNOME Shell 3.38.4.

PS: Needless to say, the operating system handles JPG images without any problems.

What could be causing this behavior?

**Edit 1:**

For me, nothing that involves jpeg is working on JavaFX. Wether I try to use jpeg as an background-image, like this very [Oracle's sample](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/css.htm), or within an ImageViewer, the result is the same (the window opens normally, as if I hadn't put any image). If I replace the file with a different extension, it works perfectly. The funny thing is that jpeg is working without issues in Swing.

Here's one sample of the possible situations in which the issue happens:

```
    /**
     * JavaFX Application
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // opens a window with the image without issue and prints true
        var fileUrl = getClass().getResource("/freemind.png");
        
        var image = new Image(fileUrl.toExternalForm());
        var imageViewer = new ImageView(image);
        var vbox = new VBox(imageViewer);
        var scene = new Scene(vbox);
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        
        System.out.println(new File(fileUrl.getFile()).exists());
    }
```

But when I replace the fileUrl with another existing jpg file, in the same directory, it opens a **blank** window, and prints true.

**Edit 2:**

I found the `-Dprism.verbose=true -Djavafx.verbose=true` debug flags, which were unknown to me, and they print the problem:

[Stack trace here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iGoU.png)

Some JPEG library, which I am not sure whether it comes embedded in the JavaFX SDK or is related to the operating system is in a different version than the expected. Now, which library is that, I don't know!

`rpm -qa | grep -P jpe?g` returns:

```
libjpeg-turbo-2.0.5-5.fc33.i686
libjpeg-turbo-2.0.5-5.fc33.x86_64
libjpeg-turbo-devel-2.0.5-5.fc33.x86_64
mjpegtools-libs-2.1.0-20.fc33.x86_64
openjpeg2-2.3.1-10.fc33.x86_64
```

Comment: “But when I replace the fileUrl with another existing jpg file…” What sort of value are you using as a replacement?  The argument must be a URI, not a file path.  You may want to print `image.getException()` to get useful information on why the image did not load.

Comment: I just change the name of the file, which is in the same folder then the previous. Actually the Image constructor takes a String with the URL, or an InputStream directly. I'm putting a String, troughthout the URL object. It works.

Comment: It depends if you use maven or ant because they load resources differently please provide the build tool that you are using and IDE if any...

Comment: @firephil Yeah, good point. The IDE is not related, I've tested with Eclipse, VSCode and manually, at the terminal. I'm primarily using maven. With maven, I tried Java FX 11, 15 and 16. I've also tried a manually downloaded JavaFX 16 SDK. Same problem. One interesting thing is that JavaFX 11 expects JPEG library version 70, while the version got is 62. JavaFX 11 is pretty old. That's very odd, since my operating system is a current one, and I keep it updated.

Comment: The method findNative, of the ClassLoader object is being called with the entryName parameter with the value `"Java_com_sun_javafx_iio_jpeg_JPEGImageLoader_initDecompressor"`. That's where the Exception is thrown.

Comment: Try different JDK provider i.e Azul+javafx,oracle jdk etc and just for curiosity JDK 8 which has JavaFX integrated. Because it is an internal native method this is probably a bug for the combination of your OS & openjdk 16

Comment: I have the same problem. You also get the error message if you check for "Image.isError()" and "Image.getException

I think it happend when I migrated to a newer Fedora version some months ago.